# Exclude folder and all sub folders and files in Visual Studio Web Deployment Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, setup-deployment

In Visual Studio 2013, I am trying to exclude an entire folder from the MSI that is created.  I tried to adding entries to the ExcludeFilter property of the "Content File from XXX (Active)" item but it doesn't appear to do anything.

I tried the following:

- Exclude specific file: \Test\TimerWorker\1\Index.js
- Exclude by wildcard: \Test\TimerWorker\1\*.*
- Exclude by sub folder: \Test**\*.*

I also tried Googling for a solution and all I could find was about adding tags to the .csproj file but nothing has worked for me yet.

**Edit 1:**

I tried following the steps outlined in the following article but they made no difference.  It looks like all I am able to do from the IDE is exclude files which are located directly under the root folder.  Does anyone know how I can exclude an entire folder and all of its subfolders and files?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-applications-project-file/

Comment: Anything not required in the installer should be excluded from the source project (csproj) instead of installer project.

Comment: Logically it does not make sense to include any dependency in project which you do not need on the output/deployment. if its not a dependency then it should not be added to csproj at first place and if its a dependency then it should not be removed from installer project.

Comment: +Munawar, it is not possible at this point in the project to separate the folder from the rest project file.  Also, what is the point of having an option to exclude if it isn't considered a good practice?

Comment: I have attached screenshots, how to exclude files from installer project, in case, you cannot exclude from source project. see answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all when adding files to installer project, you should add only primary output which will ensure to add only required dependencies.

[image: See screenshot]:

Secondly, if any unwanted file show up in the installer project then you can simply right click and exclude, It will not be copied to destination.

[image: See screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your response but this screen isn't for web based deployment projects.